# why i can't add event handlers for events of my usercontrol though page markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

i have an usercontrol that has a public event. when i use this user control in my web page and set the events to event handlers in my code behind through the page markup, event of my usercontrol don't get set and are always null even in the first page load. here is a portion of my usercontrol that has a detailsview in it which i'm trying to set the events for:

```
[Serializable(), PersistChildren(false)]
public partial class UserControl_UCDetailsView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    //here is an event for exposing detailsview1 event to the outside code
    public event DetailsViewUpdateEventHandler OnItemUpdating;
    protected void detailsview1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //here i want it not to be null but it is. by using break points i found out 
        //this is always null and never actually get set while i've set it in markup!
        if (this.OnItemUpdating != null)
            this.OnItemUpdating(sender, e);
    }
}
```

here is the portion of my **usercontrol** markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UCDetailsView.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControl_UCDetailsView" %>
<asp:DetailsView ID="detailsview1" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="detailsview1_ItemUpdating">
</asp:DetailsView>
```

and this is how i'm setting the events in my **page** markup:

```
<UC:DetailsView ID="ucDetails" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="ucDetails_ItemUpdating">
</UC:DetailsView>
```

in the ucDetails_ItemUpdaing i have a real updating logic like setting the fields and etc.
so why the heck if i set the event at the page load like the following the problem is resolved? i'm i missing something? an attribute maybe?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucDetails.OnItemUpdating += new DetailsViewUpdateEventHandler(ucDetails_ItemUpdating);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose the Add and Remove as Public properties.

Note: [I've just seen this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669160/custom-event-on-custom-control)

```
public event DetailsViewUpdateEventHandler ItemUpdating; 

public event DetailsViewUpdateEventHandler OnItemUpdating
{ 
   add { this.ItemUpdating += value;} 
   remove { this.ItemUpdating -= value;} 
}
```